# Checking string with minimum 8 digits using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have regex as follows:

```
     /^(\d|-|\(|\)|\+|\s){12,}$/
```

This will allow digits, (, ), space. But I want to ensure string contains atleast 8 digits.
Some allowed strings are as follows:

```
      (1323  ++24)233
      24243434 43
      ++++43435++4554345  434
```

It should not allow strings like:

```
     ((((((1213)))
     ++++232+++
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Look ahead` within your regex at the start..

```
/^(?=(.*\d){8,})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/
  ---------------
          |
          |->this would check for 8 or more digits
```

---

`(?=(.*\d){8,})` is `zero width look ahead` that `checks` for 0 to many character (i.e `.*`) followed by  a digit (i.e `\d`) 8 to many times (i.e.`{8,0}`)

`(?=)` is called zero width because it doesnt consume the characters..it just **checks**

---

To restict it to 14 digits you can do

```
/^(?=([^\d]*\d){8,14}[^\d]*$)[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/
```

---

try it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Haha, first Some1.Kill.The.DJ beats me to the answer, then @JanDvorak beats me to the comment. :D So this is what I got: `^(?=(?:.*\d){8})(?:\d|-|\(|\)|\+|\s){12}`

Comment: @Amadan you can't stop matching the main regex when you collect enough data. There might be undesired characters in the string.

Comment: Also, I suggest you use rubular.com for Ruby queries - Ruby's regular expressions are quite a bit more powerful than JavaScript's, modifiers are different, and if that's not reason enough, Rubular has a quite nice interface.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Good point. `^(?=(?:.*\d){8})(?:\d|-|\(|\)|\+|\s){12,}$`

Comment: You can clean up the main part to: `[\d\s\(\)+-]{12,}`

Comment: You also don't need the `?` in the lookahead since you are already matching with `*`: `(?=(.*\d){8,})`

Comment: Don't escape +- inside of [] though, do it like I do.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I checked you regex in rubular.com it is not matching for pattern '123456789'

Comment: @clickit this is becuz i used `{12,}`..Use `{8,}` instead..check out the edit

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ can you explain this part: "(?=(.*\d){8,})"

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ how do I restrict to maximum 14 digits. I tried this /^(?=(.*\d){8,14})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I written it in simple way: /^(?=(.*\d){8})(?!(.*\d){15})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/ . This works as what I want. Check is it correct regex.

Answer (score 0):

No need to mention `^`, `$`, or the "or more" part of `{8,}`, or `{12,}`, which is unclear where it comes from.

The following makes the intention transparent.

```
r = /
  (?=(?:.*\d){8})    # First condition: Eight digits
  (?!.*[^-\d()+\s])  # Second condition: Characters other than `[-\d()+\s]` should not be included.
/x
```

resulting in:

```
"(1323  ++24)233" =~ r #=> 0
"24243434 43" =~ r #=> 0
"++++43435++4554345  434" =~ r #=> 0
"((((((1213)))" =~ r #=> nil
"++++232+++" =~ r #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non regular expression solution

```
numbers = ["(1323  ++24)233", "24243434 43" , "++++43435++4554345  434", "123 456_7"]

numbers.each do |number|
  count = 0
  number.each_char do |char| 
    count += 1 if char.to_i.to_s == char
    break if count > 7
  end
  puts "#{count > 7}"
end
```

Comment: What about non-allowed characters ?

Comment: He mentions ´[\(),\s]´ in the question but the example strings also contains ´[\+]´. The definition seems unclear.