# Regex to ristrict to accept maximum 14 digits

Tags: ruby, regex

Last time I was asked for checking string for minimum 8 digits. And I got following regex:

```
    /^(?=(.*\d){8,})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/
```

You can see the question here: [Checking string with minimum 8 digits using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600290/checking-string-with-minimum-8-digits-using-regex)

Now I want to restrict string to accept maximum 14 digits in same regex. And I tried this:

```
   /^(?=(.*\d){8,14})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/
```

No luck. Please anyone help me in fixing this.

**UPDATE**

After getting 2 down votes I thought better to write my own. I constructed regex using previous regex. Following regex works for me:

```
    /^(?=(.*\d){8})(?!(.*\d){15})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/
```

Comment: Why would I even bother to reply of you accept 46% of all answers only!? Did you even upvote the 8 digit reply!?!?

Comment: Most of the questions I was asked has no acceptable answer. See my 8 digits question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600290/checking-string-with-minimum-8-digits-using-regex

Comment: why ppl are down voting? Please give the reason before you down vote.

Comment: @akuhn If ppl give answers like answers for this question. How can I accept. Tell me you accept the answers which won't work out to you or incomplete.And don't build unnecessary discussion here.

Comment: "Please anyone fix this ASAP" does not belong to stackoverflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to limit number of characters to 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10)

Comment: @clickit learn how to formulate better questions—to me the answer of tudor-constantin looks like the correct answer to your question, while your update suggests that you are actually looking for something else…

Answer (score 5):

By your request, the regex should be as simple as:

```
/^\d{8,14}$/
```

Comment: I think he wants 8-14 (assumes continuation of the previous condition with this request

Comment: I have updated the regex to match between 8 and 14 characters

Answer (score 3):

From your answer, and your other question, it seems like you are encoding a whole bunch of different rules into one increasingly complicated regex:

1. the string must be at least 12 chars long
2. it can only contain digits, parentheses, + and - signs, and spaces
3. there must be between 8 and 14 digits

While it's possible to do this with a regex, is it worthwhile? I'd argue that such a complicated regex is impossible to read, and therefore difficult to maintain.

If you split up the different criteria, it'll be much clearer.

1. `string.length >= 12`
2. `string =~ /^[\d()+-\s]+$/` - note that by using square brackets to create a character class, you don't need to escape things, which also makes it much simpler.
3. `(8..14).include?(string.count("0-9"))`  - check out the docs for [`String#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-count)

So, altogether,

```
def valid?(string)
  string.length >= 12 &&
    string =~ /^[\d()+-\s]+$/ &&
    (8..14).include?(string.count("0-9"))
end
```

It's a bit longer but it's a heck of a lot more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/^(?=(.*\d){8,14}(?!.*\d))[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/
```

If I got the placement of the negative look ahead right I should fail to match a strimg with more than 14 digits.

Comment: it is accepting more than 14 digits. I checked in rubular.com

Comment: I written my own and it works: /^(?=(.*\d){8})(?!(.*\d){15})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/ . Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding the 14 after the second instance of "8," if the previous regex achieved what you wanted - but it really is more complex than just 8-14 digits!

Comment: That won't be correct regex. I just want to restrict digits not length of the string.

Comment: Can you update the question with all required conditions? Need to understand the goal. The  look ahead (?=) allows "(any char 0 or more times, followed by a digit) 8-14 times. So it doesn't restrict to a 14digit number.....

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem. The match of 14 digits doesn't stop their from being more than 14 - need to add a negative look ahead. I'm gonna put it in a new answer so you can accept it of it works :)

Comment: I written my own and it works: /^(?=(.*\d){8})(?!(.*\d){15})[\d\(\)\s+-]{8,}$/ . Thanks for your time.